# AWS Lambda with runtime errors cannot find module

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I am trying to define a lamdba using Typscript and NodeJS via Serverless. So, I create the function handler on **Functions.ts** file:

```
export const addCREUser: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
...
}
```

and this is how I have configured serverless.yml

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: src/Functions.addCREUser
    events:
      - http:
         path: add/cre/user
         method: post
package:
  include:
    - src/**
    - node_modules/**
  exclude:
    - .gitignore
    - .idea/**
    - .git/**
    - test/**
    - package-lock.json
plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-plugin-diff
```

It compiles and generates the lamdba but, when I try to run a test from AWS Console, I get:

```
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module '@sailplane/injector'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/src/Functions.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/Runtime.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module '@sailplane/injector'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /var/task/src/Functions.js",
    "- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js",
    "- /var/runtime/Runtime.js",
    "- /var/runtime/index.js",
    "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:221:13)",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:279:17)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:34)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)",
    "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:75:12)",
    "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
  ]
}
```

This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "mavelink-aws",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Mavelink aws project",
  "main": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.15.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.101",
    "@sailplane/injector": "^3.0.0",
    "@sailplane/logger": "^4.1.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1184.0",
    "zod": "^3.17.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@middy/core": "^3.1.0",
    "@middy/http-json-body-parser": "^3.1.0",
    "serverless-plugin-diff": "^3.0.0",
    "serverless-webpack": "^5.8.0",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^3.3.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.3.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Any clue? I am using `sls deploy` command to publish on AWS.

Comment: Seems like you are missing..https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-include-dependencies...